# Flutter custom range slider for numeric values

Tags: flutter

[image]

I'm trying to create range slider horizontal, but I have no idea where to event start.
I want to select range between to values. I also want to get the select range values.

Comment: Flutter has the [RangeSlider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html) widget for that!

Comment: I want to customize like same as above. Is it possible ?